# Arduino Nano - Error stating '___' was not declared in the scope

Tags: c++, arduino, nano

I'm trying to program my Arduino so my Circuit can work properly. I have a problem with my program and its giving me error when i'm trying to compile it.

Can anybody please identify what im doing wrong. I have tried but cannot find out the problem.
The code is given below.

I'm using Arduino Nano with ATmega328P.

**Note**: The error msg is further down the code.

Thanks in advance.

```
#define select_i 3
#define pot1_i 4
#define pot2_i 5
#define en 6
#define comm 7
#define shut_off 8
#define dim1 9
#define dim2 10

//volatile variable definitions
volatile bool toa_int_flag = false;
volatile bool shut_off_flag = false;

int main(){
  //Initialise setup and serial communication
  init();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  //configuring pin modes
  pinMode(dim1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dim2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(en, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(select_i, INPUT);
  pinMode(pot1_i, INPUT);
  pinMode(pot2_i, INPUT);
  pinMode(shut_off, INPUT);
  pinMode(comm, INPUT);

  //set clock pre scaler and enable bit
  TCA0.SINGLE.CTRLA |= 0b00001011;

  //Enable waveform output by CPM0 on pin9, CMP1 on pin10 and set waveform generation mode to single-slope pwm
  TCA0.SINGLE.CTRLB |= 0b00000011;

  //Enable interrupts globally and Interrupt for PIN8/PE3
  sei();
  PORTE.PIN3CTRL |= 0b00000010;

  //Variable definitions
  float f = 2000;
  float d1 = 0.0;
  float d2 = 0.0;
  long last_comm_check = 0;
  bool print_flag = false;
  bool once1 = false;
  bool once2 = false;
  bool first = true;
  uint8_t dim_flag_up = 0;
  uint8_t dim_flag_down = 0;
  uint8_t data_comm = 0;
  uint8_t c = 0;
  uint8_t select_old = 0;
  uint8_t pot1_old = 0;
  uint8_t pot2_old = 0;
  
  uint8_t mode = 1;           //mode = 1: alter d1 by turning pot
                              //mode = 2: alter d2 by turning pot
                              
  uint8_t state = 0;          //state 0: start up     =>  set enable pin HIGH and wait for "power good" condition
                              //state 1: dimming mode =>  1. enable waveform outputs and check t1 and t2 for altering 
                              //                          the duty cycle of dim1 and dim2
                              //                          2. switch to state 3 every 10ms to check for errors
                              //state 2: error check  =>  checks for overtemperature, Iout1 under/overvoltage and Iout2
                              //                          under/overvoltage
                              //state 3: error state  =>  In case of overtemperature on the device or by pressing the shut
                              //                          off button, the code leads to this state where all output pins  
                              //                          are set LOW and while(1) is executed 


                              

  //Setup timer registers for initial frequency and duty cycle
  TCA0.SINGLE.PER = (16000000./(64.*f))-1;
  TCA0.SINGLE.CMP0 = d1 * TCA0.SINGLE.PER;
  TCA0.SINGLE.CMP1 = d2 * TCA0.SINGLE.PER;
  
  while(1){
    //set state to 3 (error state) if interrupt on pin 6 is registered
    if(shut_off_flag){
      state = 3;
      shut_off_flag = false;
    }
    
    //read value of millis()
    long now = millis();

    //print error message if stuck contact on pot1/2 is detected
    if(print_flag == true && once1 == true){
      Serial.println("Potentiometer is stuck on one contact. Please move it in the other direction to free the contact again.");
      Serial.println("All signals are beeing ignored till the contact is free again.");
      print_flag = false;
      once1 = false;
    }
    if(print_flag == true && once2 == true){
      Serial.println("Potentiometer is stuck on one contact. Please move it in the other direction to free the contact again.");
      Serial.println("All signals are beeing ignored till the contact is free again.");
      print_flag = false;
      once2 = false;
    }

    if(state == 0){
        //set enable HIGH
        digitalWrite(en, HIGH);
        //check for power good condition
        if(digitalRead(comm) == 1){
          state = 1;
        }
    }
    else if(state == 1){
        //set CMP0EN, and CMP1EN to enable waveform output on dim1 and dim2
        TCA0.SINGLE.CTRLB |= 0b00110000;
        
        //Read select button input and pot1, pot2 inputs
        int select = digitalRead(select_i);
        int pot1 = digitalRead(pot1_i);
        int pot2 = digitalRead(pot2_i);

        //ignore postive voltage on pot1/2 when device starts up
        if(first == true){
          if(pot1 || pot2){
            pot1_old = 1;
            pot2_old = 1;
            first = false;
          }
        }
    
        //check for positive edge and set mode for altering dim1 or dim2
        if(select == 1 && select_old != 1){
          if(mode == 2){
            mode = 1;
          }
          else{
            mode = 2;
          }
        }

        //check for postive edge on pot1_i and set edge_pot1
        if(pot1 == 1 && pot1_old != 1){
          dim_flag_up = 1;
        }

        //check for postive edge on pot2_i and set edge_pot2
        if(pot2 == 1 && pot2_old != 1){
          dim_flag_down = 1;
        }

        //clear both dim_flags after altering d upwards
        if(dim_flag_up == 2){
          if(dim_flag_down == 1){
            dim_flag_up = 0;
            dim_flag_down = 0;
          }
        }

        //clear both dim_flags after altering d downwards
        if(dim_flag_down == 2){
          if(dim_flag_up == 1){
            dim_flag_up = 0;
            dim_flag_down = 0;
          }
        }

        //if edge on pot1 is detected start altering d upwards 
        if(dim_flag_up == 1 && dim_flag_down != 2){
          //filter stuck contact on pot2
          if(pot2 != 0 || pot2_old != 0){
            print_flag = true;
            dim_flag_up = 2;
          }
          else{
            //flag to print Error Message once every time a contact gets stuck on the pot2
            once2 = true;
            
            //set dim_flag_up to 2: waiting for following edge on pot2
            dim_flag_up = 2;
            
            //if mode is 1 alter d1
            if(mode == 1){
              d1 += 0.01;
              if(d1 > 0.99){
                d1 = 0.99;
              }
              TCA0.SINGLE.CMP0 = d1 * TCA0.SINGLE.PER;
              Serial.print("Tastgrad d1: ");
              Serial.println(d1);
              
            }
            //if mode is 2 alter d2
            else if(mode == 2){
              d2 += 0.01;
              if(d2 > 0.99){
                d2 = 0.99;
              }
              TCA0.SINGLE.CMP1 = d2 * TCA0.SINGLE.PER;
              Serial.print("Tastgrad d2: ");
              Serial.println(d2);
            }
          }
        }

        //if edge on pot2 is detected start altering d downwards 
        if(dim_flag_down == 1 && dim_flag_up != 2){
          //filter stuck contact on pot2
          if(pot1 != 0 || pot1_old != 0){
            print_flag = true;
            dim_flag_down = 2;
          }
          else{
            //flag to print Error Message once every time a contact gets stuck on the pot1
            once1 = true;
            
            //set dim_flag_down to 2:waiting for following egde on pot1
            dim_flag_down = 2;
            
            //if mode is 1 alter d1
            if(mode == 1){
              d1 -= 0.01;
              if(d1 < 0.0){
                d1 = 0.0;
              }
              TCA0.SINGLE.CMP0 = d1 * TCA0.SINGLE.PER;
              Serial.print("Tastgrad d1: ");
              Serial.println(d1);
            }
            //if mode is 2 alter d2
            else if(mode == 2){
              d2 -= 0.01;
              if(d2 < 0.0){
                d2 = 0.0;
              }
              TCA0.SINGLE.CMP1 = d2 * TCA0.SINGLE.PER;
              Serial.print("Tastgrad d2: ");
              Serial.println(d2);
            }
          }
        }

        select_old = select;
        pot1_old = pot1;
        pot2_old = pot2;

        //switch to error checking state every 10ms
        if((now-10) >= last_comm_check){
          state = 2;
          last_comm_check = now;
        }
    }
    else if(state == 2){
        //check for overtemperture condition
        if(digitalRead(comm) == 0){
          Serial.println("Temperature of Led-driver too high!");
          state = 3;
        }
        else{
          //set d2 = d1 for reading data from device
          //TCA0.SINGLE.CMP1 = TCA0.SINGLE.CMP0;
          
          //enable timer ovf interrupt to read data from comm
          TCA0.SINGLE.INTCTRL |= 0b00000001;
          
          //check for over- and undervoltage error messages
          digitalWrite(en,LOW);
          digitalWrite(en,HIGH);

          //set data_comm to zero
          data_comm = 0;

          //read four bits from the comm pin
          while(c < 4){
            if(toa_int_flag = true){
              uint8_t buffer_c = digitalRead(comm);
              data_comm |= (buffer_c<<(3-c));
              c++;
              toa_int_flag = false;
            }
          }
          c = 0;
          
          //set d2 to old value
          //TCA0.SINGLE.CMP1 = d2 * TCA0.SINGLE.PER;

          //check the read data for one of the following error conditions and if None were detected return to state 1
          switch(data_comm){
            case 0:
              Serial.println("case 0: Overtemperature Condition occurred while reading COMM-Pin");
            case 1:
              Serial.println("ERROR: Overvoltage IOUT1");
              state = 3;
              break;
            case 3:
              Serial.println("ERROR: Overvoltage IOUT2");
              state = 3;
              break;
            case 5:
              Serial.println("ERROR: Undervoltage IOUT1");
              state = 3;
              break;
            case 7:
              Serial.println("ERROR: Undervoltage IOUT2");
              state = 3;
              break;
            case 15:
              //Serial.println("No Errors detected");
              state = 1;
              break;
            default:
              Serial.println("ERROR: unknown Error condition occurred.");
              state = 3;
              break;
          }
        }
    }
    else if(state == 3){
      //Set all Output Pins low and execute while(1) to prevent device from starting again
      digitalWrite(en, LOW);
      digitalWrite(dim1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(dim2, LOW);
      Serial.println("Device is in Error-State. All Output-Pins were turned off.");
      Serial.println("To use the device again, it needs to be reset. Make sure that no error condition is remaining before reseting the device!");
      while(1);
              
      }
   }
}

//raise Interrupt every time the timer counter is reset
ISR(TCA0_OVF_vect){
  toa_int_flag = true;
  TCA0.SINGLE.INTFLAGS |= bit(0);
}

//raise Interrupt every time a positive edge is detected on PIN8/PE3
ISR(PORTE_PORT_vect){
  shut_off_flag = true;
  PORTE.INTFLAGS |= bit(3);
}
```

**Error Message**

```
C:\Users\: 
In function 'int main()':
charge_light_pwm:30:3: error: 'TCA0' was not declared in this scope
   TCA0.SINGLE.CTRLA |= 0b00001011;
   ^~~~
C:\Users\ 
note: suggested alternative: 'TWA0'
   TCA0.SINGLE.CTRLA |= 0b00001011;
   ^~~~
   TWA0
charge_light_pwm:37:3: error: 'PORTE' was not declared in this scope
   PORTE.PIN3CTRL |= 0b00000010;
   ^~~~~
C:\Users\ 
note: suggested alternative: 'PORT0'
   PORTE.PIN3CTRL |= 0b00000010;
   ^~~~~
   PORT0
C:\Users\
In function 'void TCA0_OVF_vect()':
charge_light_pwm:329:3: error: 'TCA0' was not declared in this scope
   TCA0.SINGLE.INTFLAGS |= bit(0);
   ^~~~
C:\Users\
note: suggested alternative: 'TWA0'
   TCA0.SINGLE.INTFLAGS |= bit(0);
   ^~~~
   TWA0
C:\Users\
In function 'void PORTE_PORT_vect()':
charge_light_pwm:335:3: error: 'PORTE' was not declared in this scope
   PORTE.INTFLAGS |= bit(3);
   ^~~~~
C:\Users\ 
note: suggested alternative: 'PORT0'
   PORTE.INTFLAGS |= bit(3);
   ^~~~~
   PORT0
exit status 1
'TCA0' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mre], with emphasis on the *minimal* part.

Comment: I doubt that the message actually says "'___' was not declared in the scope".

Comment: Yes thats right. I wrote it because there are multiple variables not found. Let me edit my msg and add the error msg as well :)

Comment: The code you show, too long as it is, is missing any header file inclusions. Perhaps the symbols you're missing is defined in some header file you don't `#include`?

Comment: Why are you implementing the `main()` function? Arduino framework uses `setup()` and `loop()`.

Comment: Yes i tried checking that too. According to the person, this program was working before and suddenly stopped working for no reason. that is my concern whats suppose to be the problem. But thankyou. Let me check the header files

Comment: gre_gor, main() can also be used with init() and for loop instead of setup() and loop() according to my understanding.

Comment: @Juraj Thankyou for your answer. In tools menu i cannot turn off ATmega328P but can only change it to ATmega328P (Old bootloader) or ATmega168. Both of them are giving me the same errors.

Comment: https://arbaranwal.github.io/tutorial/2017/06/23/atmega328-register-reference.html looks like PORTE and TCA0 don't exist. The compiler is suggesting you alternatives. Have you tried them?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Thankyou for your comment. Yes i tried the alternatives but then it gives error about singles not existing. I believe that the program is fine i just need to declare them somehow and thats what i am confused where can i declare them and how.

Comment: do you have a classic Nano with 328p or Nano Every with 4809?

Answer (score 0):

The code is for modern AVR controllers like tinyAVR or megaAVR series. TCA0 is a timer peripheral there. It will not work for classic Nano.

Arduino Nano Every with ATmega4809 from the megaAVR series may be compatible with your program. If your board is Nano Every, then select Nano Every in Tools menu.